# Angular2 ,TypeScript not build in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, angular

i am new at angular2 and TypeScript. moreover i am trying set up angular2 with Visual Studio 2013. i followed 5 min Quickstart tutorial from angular2 site.here is my code
**app.component.ts**

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
selector: 'myapp',
template: '<h1>My Name is Himadri</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->

    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
 
  
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        System.import('Dev/app.component.js');
        System.import('Dev/main.js');
    </script>
 
    <div id="content">
        <myapp>Loading..</myapp>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

when i build the project  it shows no error. but the when run it do not show anything. i dont know why..?? do i miss anything?? the js file created by Visual studio against .ts file is as follows

app.component.js--Created from app.component.ts

```js
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var core_1 = require('angular2/core');
var AppComponent = (function () {
    function AppComponent() {
    }
    AppComponent = __decorate([
        core_1.Component({
            selector: 'myapp',
            template: '<h1>My Name is Himadri</h1>'
        })
    ], AppComponent);
    return AppComponent;
}());
exports.AppComponent = AppComponent;
```

main.js -- created from main.ts

```js
   "use strict";
   var browser_1 = require('angular2/platform/browser');
   var app_component_1 = require('./app.component');
   browser_1.bootstrap(app_component_1.AppComponent);
   //# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

can any one describe what is the problem?

Comment: When the app lunch in the browser, do you see at least the Loading..? Does it says anything in console log? (press F12 and then navigate to Console)

Comment: You could try using the [Angular 2 CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)'s `ng serve` and then that'll watch when you edit+save your files from Visual Studio. Most people use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which is Angular 2 ready out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples of code I see some differences against the tutorial. This worked for me couple of days ago (in Visual Studio 2015, but that shouldn't be the difference, since you can compile it successfully to JS)..

I have TypeScript project (in VS solution type is called ***HTML Application with TypeScript***)

This should be your starting set of files:

[image]

Content of all files can be completely identical like at the end of the tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Hope this helps.